# Use regex to remove unwanted commas

Tags: java, regex

I am creating an app in which I have generated string like this:

```
 hihibjj,,,,,,,ghjjjj, , ,kartik.isworking@gmail.com,,,,karan.adep@gmail.com, android-developer-support@google.com, prerna.mungekar@hamarisuraksha.com
```

What I want is to delete unwanted commas, only single comma separated values should be present.

Code that I have tried

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < emailSeperated.size(); j++) {
    if (temp[i].trim().equals(emailSeperated.get(j).trim())) {
      strEmailValue = strEmailValue.replace(temp[i], "").trim();
      Log.e("strEmail trimmed value", strEmailValue);
    } else if (temp[i].trim().equals(emailSeperated.get(j).trim())) {
      strEmailValue = strEmailValue.replaceAll(temp[i] + ",", "").trim();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use lookbehind also.

Regex:

```
(?<=,) ?,
```

Replacement string:

```
Empty string
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iM7vX1/15)

```
System.out.println("hihibjj,,,,,,,ghjjjj, , ,kartik.isworking@gmail.com,,,,karan.adep@gmail.com, android-developer-support@google.com, prerna.mungekar@hamarisuraksha.com".replaceAll("(?<=,) ?,", ""));
```

**Output:**

```
hihibjj,ghjjjj,kartik.isworking@gmail.com, karan.adep@gmail.com, android-developer-support@google.com, prerna.mungekar@hamarisuraksha.com
```

Comment: What's the problem in that?

Comment: in result sometimes i m getting something like this ", , ,"

Comment: post the input please.

Comment: hihibjj,,,,,,,ghjjjj, , ,kartik.isworking@gmail.com,,,,karan.adep@gmail.com, android-developer-support@google.com, prerna.mungekar@hamarisuraksha.com

Comment: yes, because the commas are seperated by spaces. Below answer also won't work. Paste the above comment in your question.

Answer (score 7):

Just find: `,,+` and replace with: `,`

Comment: `,{2,}` would work as well and (depending on the person) may be preferred as more readable/less confusing

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight: I prefer mine because it contains less characters :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
String as = "as,,,,,,";
as= as.replaceAll(",,+",",");
```

Comment: This will do more work than necessary because it replaces one comma by one ccomma.